# Creating an array variable with a variable number of elements

Tags: arrays, vba, variables, dynamic, constants

I want to define an array variable to have a variable number of elements depending on the m number of results returned from a search. I get an error "Constant Expression Required" on:

```
Dim cmodels(0 To m) As String
```

Here is my complete code

```
Dim foundRange As Range
Dim rangeToSearch As Range
Set rangeToSearch = Selection
Set foundRange = rangeToSearch.Find(What:="Lights", After:=ActiveCell,            
LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False) 'First Occurrence
    m = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Selection, "Lights")
 Dim secondAddress As String
If (Not foundRange Is Nothing) Then
    Dim count As Integer: count = 0
    Dim targetOccurrence As Integer: targetOccurrence = 2
    Dim found As Boolean
    z = 1
    Dim cmodels(0 To m) As String
    Do Until z = m
    z = z + 1
        foundRange.Activate
        Set foundRange = rangeToSearch.FindNext(foundRange)
        If Not foundRange.Next Is Nothing Then
        z(m) = ActiveCell(Offset(0, 2))
        End If
    Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following code comments:

```
Sub redimVsRedimPreserve()

    'I generally declare arrays I know I will resize
    'without a fixed size initially..
    Dim cmodels() As String
    Dim m As Integer
    m = 3

    'this will wipe out all data in the array
    ReDim cmodels(0 To m) As String

    'you can also use this if you want to save all information in the variable
    cmodels(2) = "test"
    ReDim Preserve cmodels(0 To m) As String

    'this will still keep "test"
    Debug.Print "With redim preserve, the value is: " & cmodels(2)

    'using just 'redim'
    ReDim cmodels(0 To m) As String
    Debug.Print "with just redim, the value is: " & cmodels(2)



End Sub
```

Also note that using `Redim Preserve` frequently (such as a loop) can be an operation which takes some time.

Comment: This has become a popular question; kudos enderland for a great response.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim cmodels() As String
'...
ReDim cmodels(0 to m)
```

Comment: `Dim cmodels as String()`

Comment: `Dim cmodels as String()` results in an error, and `Dim cmodels(m) As String` gives the same problem that is being asked about...

Comment: Right, notice it now, it's VBA... Different from VB.