# Excel VBA: Cant add to an array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter

I have run into a problem, im fairly new to VBA but learning fast. I have been trying to right this code below, to look through a column and pick out all the possible values that rows of data take in this column for use in another bit of code.

I cant get the array to work, i could just be doing it wrong.
In case its not clear, it should check the value of a cell in column I and if it is a value (and if it hasnt been stored already (code shown but not used yet)) then the value is stored in the array and the position in the array and the position down the column incremented.

Another question i havent looked at yet is then how to arrange the values in the array by name etc? The values in this case will be AHU1, AHU2, AHU3 etc up to about AHU5 or 6, I also intend to implent a bit of code that will expand the Array if necassery (from smaller so it is not bigger than it needs to be)

EDIT: another problem i havnt worked out yet is why the If statement always causes the value to be added to the array (which it doesnt)

```
Do
    If IsNull(V1.Range("I" & i)) = False Then 'And V1.Range("I" & i).Value <> (Val(AHUArray(1)) Or Val(AHUArray(2)) Or Val(AHUArray(3)) Or Val(AHUArray(4)) Or Val(AHUArray(5)) Or Val(AHUArray(6)) Or Val(AHUArray(7)) Or Val(AHUArray(8)) Or Val(AHUArray(9)) Or Val(AHUArray(10))) Then   'And (does not equal any other values in the array
            AHUArray(ArrayDim) = V1.Range("I" & i).Text
            i = i + 1
            ArrayDim = ArrayDim + 1
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
Loop While i <= LastRow
```

Any ideas?, help will be greatly appreciated!

These are the definitions from before this code encase its a probloem with these (as it has been in the past but i dont think it is?

```
Dim V1 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim C As Range
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim AHUArray(1 To 10) As String
Dim DestCell As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ArrayDim As Integer



Set V1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("V1")
Set AHU = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AHU")

LastRow = V1.Range("A:A").Find("*", V1.Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
DestCell = 3
ArrayDim = 1
i = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
IsNull(V1.Range("I" & i)) = False
```

to

```
V1.range("I" & i).value <> ""
```

When you use `IsNull` like that you are always going to get true, because you are asking, "is this range value which I just created and defined Null?"

Regarding dynamically growing the array, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18409611/1048539) for examples on how to do so.

Comment: Thanks, realised this i went for an IsEmpty and a made another function. My solution is added as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this is how i managed it. Realised using IsNull was foolish, and managed to make a check function using how UBound returns -1 is it doesnt find anthing

```
   Do
       If IsEmpty(V1.Range("I" & i)) = False And IsInArray(V1.Range("I" & i).Value, AHUArray) = False Then '(does not equal any other values in the array
            AHUArray(ArrayDim) = V1.Range("I" & i).Value
            i = i + 1
            ArrayDim = ArrayDim + 1
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
Loop While i <= LastRow
```

and this is the other check function

```
Function ArrayCountIs(ArrayToCount As Variant) As Integer

Dim i As Integer
Dim ArrayCount As Integer
ArrayCount = 0
i = 0
For i = LBound(ArrayToCount) To UBound(ArrayToCount)
    If Not (ArrayToCount(i)) = "" Then
        ArrayCount = ArrayCount + 1
    End If
Next

ArrayCountIs = ArrayCount

End Function
```